# jQuery Determine if a matched class has a given id

Tags: jquery

What is jQuery has id equivalent of the following statement?

```
$('#mydiv').hasClass('foo')
```

so you could give a class name and check that it contains a supplied id.

something like:

```
$('.mydiv').hasId('foo')
```

Comment: I want to apply a style to a certain div. For example at load time all with a class of foo would be shown, but I may want to toggle one instance of the class foo off that has an id of bar.

Comment: Then you would simply do `$('#bar.foo').toggle();` you will only ever have one id as they are REQUIRED to be unique to the document. if you ant to only toggle that id if it is of class `foo` then just add the class to the id selector. if the selector finds an empty set nothing will happen, if it finds a set with results (of which there will only be one) then it will toggle the element. i think youre overthinking this.

Comment: just to say it's frustrating people saying "why would you ever want to do that?" when I am trying to do this right now.

The problem with hasClass is it returns True if ANY element that matches the selector has the given class. So where I have many p with class "cake" and additional class names for each ("one", "two" etc) I am having a problem. I want to select the general set of p.cake and then have a conditional (if class="one" - $var=23 - etc).

The point is that I am trying to pass a different $var depending on the additional class name. I'm trying not to have to repeat the whole bit o

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You can bake that logic into the selector by [combining multiple selectors](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_basics#Combining_Selectors). For instance, we could target all elements with a given id, that also have a particular class:

```
$("#foo.bar"); // Matches <div id="foo" class="bar">
```

This should look similar to something you'd write in CSS. Note that it won't apply to all `#foo` elements (though there should only be one), and it won't apply to all `.bar` elements (though there may be many). It will only reference elements that qualify on both attributes.

jQuery also has a great [`.is` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) that lets your determine whether an element has certain qualities. You can test a jQuery collection against a string selector, an HTML Element, or another jQuery object. In this case, we'll just check it against a string selector:

```
$(".bar:first").is("#foo"); // TRUE if first '.bar' in document is also '#foo'
```

Comment: +1 for `is()`. There should be a `.hasId()` selector just because it's  seems like an obvious partner to `.hasClass()` really...

Answer (score 44):

I would probably use `$('.mydiv').is('#foo');` That said if you know the Id why wouldnt you just apply it to the selector in the first place?

Comment: Maybe the code is going into a callback function that needs to handle a certain case differently.  So, the function is passed a jQuery object automatically with unknown attributes.  In this case, $('your answer').is('helpful');

Comment: I can think of any number of reasons.  What if you want to apply a mobile specific setting, like if an element has the id="mobile".  The why isn't important.

Comment: Well only 1 element should ever have a given `id` otherwise it should be some other attribute... I suppose if the structural location of the element in question changes based on the page or client/user-agent then ok, but other than that...

Answer (score 19):

update: sorry misunderstood the question, removed `.has()` answer.

another alternative way, create `.hasId()` plugin

```js
// the plugin
$.fn.hasId = function(id) {
  return this.attr('id') == id;
};

// select first class
$('.mydiv').hasId('foo') ?
  console.log('yes') : console.log('no');

// select second class
// $('.mydiv').eq(1).hasId('foo')
// or
$('.mydiv:eq(1)').hasId('foo') ?
  console.log('yes') : console.log('no');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mydiv" id="foo"></div>
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I think you misinterpreted the question: [has() API](http://api.jquery.com/has/) reports this:
Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a *descendant* that matches the selector or DOM element. The OP is asking how to test if the element with class 'myDiv' has also the Id foo, while has() will look for descendants of 'myDiv' having the Id 'foo'.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say that you're iterating through some DOM objects and you wanna find and catch an element with a certain ID

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="fo"><div>
    <div id="bar"><div>
</div>
```

You can either write something like to find

```
$('#myDiv').find('#bar')
```

*Note that if you were to use a class selector, the find method will return all the matching elements.*

or you could write an iterating function that will do more advanced work

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div id="fo"><div>
    <div id="bar"><div>
    <div id="fo1"><div>
    <div id="bar1"><div>
    <div id="fo2"><div>
    <div id="bar2"><div>
</div>

$('#myDiv div').each(function() {
   if($(this).attr('id') == 'bar1')
       //do something with bar1
});
```

Same code could be easily modified for class selector.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="fo"><div>
    <div class="bar"><div>
    <div class="fo"><div>
    <div class="bar"><div>
    <div class="fo"><div>
    <div class="bar"><div>
</div>

$('#myDiv div').each(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('bar'))
       //do something with bar
});
```

I'm glad you solved your problem with index(), what ever works for you.I hope this will help others with the same problem. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#' + theMysteryId + '.someClass').each(function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

Comment: the each is unneeded because there will never be more than one `#theMysteryId`.

Comment: Well it saves you the trouble of assigning it to a variable, checking to see if the length is non-empty, and then proceeding with the code. If the selector matches nothing jQuery just won't call the "each" function, so it's nice and clean.  Now if all you want to do is call some jQuery API, then sure.

Answer (score 4):

Just to say I eventually solved this using index().

NOTHING else seemed to work.

So for sibling elements this is a good work around if you are first selecting by a common class and then want to modify something differently for each specific one.

EDIT: for those who don't know (like me) index() gives an index value for each element that matches the selector, counting from 0, depending on their order in the DOM. As long as you know how many elements there are with class="foo" you don't need an id.

Obviously this won't always help, but someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 4):

Check if element's ID is exist

```js
if ($('#id').attr('id') == 'id')
{
  //OK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also check if the id element is used by doing so:

```
if(typeof $(.div).attr('id') == undefined){
   //element has no id
} else {
   //element has id selector
}
```

I use this method for global dataTables and specific ordered dataTables

Comment: the undefined should be in quotes in order to work like so 'undefined'