# if closest has id in jquery then do something

Tags: jquery

There is a question here: If closest parent has a certain class then do something which doesn't have the answer I'm looking for.

Currently I select a ul for the clicked item with this:

```
$(this).closest("ul")
```

This returns the correct object which is this:
[image]

I need to run an if statement to do something like this:

```
if($(this).closest("ul") has, contains "quantity" ) {then do something}
```

The statement above is not correct syntax but just an example of what I need.  The "quantity" I'm looking for is not always going to be called quantity it will change.  I can do "addClass" but that's not what I'm looking for.  I need to check if the specific closest ul is quel to a value.

The html element looks like this:

```
<ul class="d-none po-list" name="quantity" id="quantity" data-dependent="quantity" data-cost="" style="display: none;"><li value="25" data-cost="94.00"><span>25</span></li><li value="50" data-cost="99.00"><span>50</span></li><li value="100" data-cost="137.00"><span>100</span></li><li value="250" data-cost="278.00"><span>250</span></li><li value="500" data-cost="405.00"><span>500</span></li><li value="1000" data-cost="682.00"><span>1000</span></li><li value="2500" data-cost="1698.00"><span>2500</span></li><li value="5000" data-cost="2792.00"><span>5000</span></li></ul>
```

Comment: What is the actual HTML of that `<ul>` and what are you looking for in that HTML?

Comment: paste your html code

Comment: `quantity` as in you want to check to see if the `ul` has a given `id` attribute?

Comment: @chazsolo yes correct id or class

Comment: `is('.quantity, #quantity')` would return true if the element has the class or id of quantity.

Comment: You're looking for [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)... `$(this).closest('ul').is('#quantity')`. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253457/jquery-determine-if-a-matched-class-has-a-given-id

Comment: @David html code added

Comment: The word "quantity" appears three times in the `ul` you've shown. Which attribute do you want to check for that string?

Comment: Well his question title is asking for class which would literally be $(this).closest(whatever) .hasClass("this-class-name").

Comment: @AndrewG yeah, but none of the items with "quantity" are the class attribute, which is confusing.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah just answering in case he wanted to know how to do it for class name as well.

Comment: @AndrewG I fixed the title however this ".hasClass" would bring ANY ul on the dom that has that class which isn't what I would want.  The answer by Taplar is correct is()